# Healing This Gaps

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am working with a mesh that has a series of very thin gaps. Ideally this appear sheet-like. I would like to avoid manually adding faces of dilating other areas significantly. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post and try to be more clear because it's difficult to understand what you want exactly. Do you want to fill the gaps?

Comment: Yes my goal is to fill these gaps, this should be a solid object without holes. I have tried a few modifiers such as solidify, but these change the mesh in other areas in ways that don't work for me.